# Kafka SpringBoot StreamListener - how to consume multiple topics in order?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have multiple StreamListener-annotated methods consuming from different topics. But some of these topics need to be read from the "earliest" offset to populate an in-memory map (something like a state machine) and then consume from other topics that might have commands in them that should be executed against the "latest" state machine.

Current code looks something like:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding({InputChannel.class, OutputChannel.class})
@Slf4j
public class KafkaListener {

    @StreamListener(target = InputChannel.EVENTS)
    public void event(Event event) {
        // do something with the event
    }

    @StreamListener(target = InputChannel.COMMANDS)
    public void command(Command command) {
        // do something with the command only after all events have been processed
    }

}
```

I tried to add some horrible code that gets the kafka topic offset metadata from the incoming event messages and then uses a semaphore to block the command until a certain percentage of the total offset is reached by the event. It kinda works but makes me sad, and it will be awful to maintain once we have 20 or so topics that all depend on one another.

Does SpringBoot / Spring Streams have any built-in mechanism to do this, or is there some common pattern that people use that I'm not aware of?

**TL;DR**: How do I process all messages from topic A before consuming any from topic B, without doing something dirty like sticking a Thread.sleep(60000) in the consumer for topic B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [kafka consumer binding property](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties) `resetOffsets`

> **resetOffsets**
>
> Whether to reset offsets on the consumer to the value provided by `startOffset`. Must be false if a `KafkaRebalanceListener` is provided; see Using a KafkaRebalanceListener.
>
> Default: false.
>
> **startOffset**
>
> The starting offset for new groups. Allowed values: `earliest` and `latest`. If the consumer group is set explicitly for the consumer 'binding' (through spring.cloud.stream.bindings..group), 'startOffset' is set to earliest. Otherwise, it is set to latest for the anonymous consumer group. Also see `resetOffsets` (earlier in this list).
>
> Default: null (equivalent to earliest).

You can also add a [KafkaBindingRebalanceListener](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#rebalance-listener) and perform seeks on the consumer.

**EDIT**

You can also set `autoStartup` to false on the second listener, and start the binding when you are ready. Here's an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Gitter55Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gitter55Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerEndpointCustomizer<KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<?, ?>> customizer() {
        return (endpoint, dest, group) -> {
            endpoint.setOnPartitionsAssignedSeekCallback((assignments, callback) -> {
                assignments.keySet().forEach(tp -> callback.seekToBeginning(tp.topic(), tp.partition()));
            });
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String value, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) byte[] key) {
        System.out.println(new String(key) + ":" + value);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template,
            BindingsEndpoint bindings) {

        return args -> {
            while (true) {
                template.send("gitter55", "foo".getBytes(), "bar".getBytes());

                System.out.println("Hit enter to start");
                System.in.read();
                bindings.changeState("input", State.STARTED);
            }
        };

    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=gitter55
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=gitter55
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.auto-startup=false
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this helps me - what I need is to process all messages from topic A before consuming any from topic B, without doing something dirty like sticking a Thread.sleep(60000) in the consumer for topic B

Comment: It enables the first listener to re-read the entire topic; you should use a latch or similar to prevent the second listener from listening until, say, an idle container event has been received for the first container.

Comment: You can also set `autoStartup` to false on the second listener, and start the binding when you are ready. See the edit to my answer for an example I wrote some time ago.

Comment: Consuming from the beginning seems to work okay by just using RandomUUID as the groupId, but the "auto-startup=false" / "bindings.changeState" is the bit that I was missing, thanks!